# How to run "write.csv" on an Rscript while in docker?

Tags: r, macos, docker, csv

I am trying to run a logistic regression model through docker and generate a csv file at the end with the results, to be put in a output folder in the docker image. However, I can't get it to generate the csv because I keep getting this error:

```
Warning message:
In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = if (type ==  :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: write.csv -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> write.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'output/predictions.csv': No such file or directory
```

Why would I need the csv file to already be in the image, if I am trying to generate it? Is there a way to get around this at all?

Here is my R code for generating the model results:

```
predictAll = predict(model1, type="response", newdata = RatioData)
id <- RatioData$id
predictAllframe <- data.frame(id, predictAll)
write.csv(predictAllframe, file = 'output/predictions.csv', row.names=FALSE)
```

and here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest

#R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages('mosaic', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('plyr', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', dependencies=T)"
RUN R -e "install.packages('dplyr', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('purrr', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggplot2', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('caret', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('e1071', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"

# Move to the app folder
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy and run the Rscript.
COPY /src/model-1.R .
CMD R -e "source('/src/model-1.R')"

#data
ADD /data1.tar.gz .

# Copy Bash scripts expected by the IT infrastructure
COPY model1command.sh .

# Add executable permission to Bash scripts
RUN chmod +x model1command.sh
```

The model1command.sh file just contains the following command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

Rscript /app/model-1.R
```

and the docker run command that I used is below:

```
docker run \
     -v $(pwd)/data1:/data:ro \
     -v $(pwd)/output:/output:rw \
     -v $(pwd)/scratch:/scratch:rw \
     awesome-model:v1 bash /app/model1command.sh
```

Thank you so much, I have been trying to figure this out for almost a week.

Comment: Does your `$(pwd)/output` exist? It's likely R is complaining about the directory `output`, not the file `predictions.csv`. You can typically resolve it with `dir.create('/output/', showWarnings = FALSE)`

Comment: my guess is the directory `output` doesn't exist. precede the `write.csv` with `dir.create('output', showWarnings=FALSE)`, or create that directory with the `RUN` command (`mkdir output`)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think it exists, as I have a folder called output in the directory--this is the list it gives me when I check ls: -v, output, data1, Dockerfile, scratch, data1.tar.gz, model1command.sh, src. I will definitely try adding that command to the Rscript, though!

Comment: @Emma Consider pushing your Docker image to a public repository (like Dockerhub). Your example is not fully reproducible since we have don't access to your `model-1.R` or your `data1.tar.gz`. Being able to pull the image from Dockerhub will help with reproducing the problem.

Comment: this is probably in the directory where you have the `Dockerfile` right? if so, you need to _copy_ that folder into the docker environment -- it won't be copied by default. That's the `COPY` command. I see you've used it to copy the model script, but I don't see the corresponding command for your output folder.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think the idea is to map with `-v $(pwd)/output:/output:rw` at runtime.

Comment: ^ Yes this is another think to consider. Maybe depends on use case -- it would help to explain why that is a good idea :)

Comment: @ArtemSokolov thank you for the advice, I will do that

Comment: @MichaelChirico thank you, I have not tried that yet! Will try now

Comment: @MichaelChirico you are the best, it finally worked!!!

Comment: @ArtemSokolov thank you so much, it finally worked!!!

Comment: HTH. BTW, a tip for debugging Docker -- if the image build fine up through line `n`, you can simply comment out lines `n` onwards & build the image through `n-1`. Then you can "log in" to the half-built container with `docker run`, and try to continue the build yourself manually / interactively from there. Makes it easier than sitting & waiting to `docker build` each time

Answer (score 0):

The route is not formatted correctly, leave any file in `R` console and copy the correct name, after replace this name in `write.table`, for example:

```
Write.table = (filename, "paste rute"_nombre.csv", row.names=F)
```